# Primeng: FormControl assigned to p-inputNumber ignores [max]-property when using setValue()

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a FormControl inside a FormGroup where I can manually type in a value, or it will calculate a value for me depending on other values. I call function inside my `ngOnit()` that will calculate the value in certain circumstances and will call `setValue()` on the FormControl.

I have a max value defined for my control, which will not get triggered if setting the value by `setValue()`. It can happen that the calculation is higher than the max value. In that case, it should use the max value.

Is there a way how i can retrigger the validation or am I just missing something? I know I can just check inside my function if the value is higher than allowed. I am looking for an easier solution. I have also tried triggering `updateValueAndValidity()` on the control but it did nothing.

```
<p-inputNumber [formControl]="control"
               mode="currency" currency="EUR"
               [min]="0" [max]="5000"></p-inputNumber>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

Apologies I made a mistake, you are mixing reactive and template driven methods of forms that is the root cause. Please change the template driven method of adding validators `[max]` and replace it with the reactive  method, which is shown below, where we specify the validator as `Validators.maxLength(100)` for example!

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { InputTextModule } from 'primeng/inputtext';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [InputTextModule, ReactiveFormsModule, CommonModule],
  template: `
  <form [formGroup]="form">
    <input type="text" pInputText [formControl]="form.controls.input" id="input" name="input"> 
  </form>
  {{
    form.controls.input.errors | json
  }}
  <button (click)="setInputValue()"> set input value</button>
  `,
})
export class App {
  form = new FormGroup<{ input: FormControl<string> }>({
    input: new FormControl<string>('', {
      nonNullable: true,
      validators: [Validators.minLength(0), Validators.maxLength(5)],
    }),
  });
  name = 'Angular';

  setInputValue() {
    const control: FormControl<string> = <FormControl<string>>(
      this.form.get('input')
    );
    control?.setValue('sdfasdfasdfasdfasdf');
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-djspjc?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)

---

After doing the `setValue` sometimes it will get missed, for these scenarios, you have the function [`updateValueAndValidity()`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#updatevalueandvalidity) this will ensure that the validators are triggered and the error gets shown.

```
const control = this.form.get('controlName');
control.setValue(5001);
control.updateValueAndValidity();
```

Comment: I suspect there is no validation logic related to `min` and `max` . primeng just calls [validateValue](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/2585e7c8f6c7f5a37d97e7712f9fb293bd4f6065/src/app/components/inputnumber/inputnumber.ts#L1233) on user interactions like `spin, tab, enter, blur`

Comment: Most probably this will work as a workaround `this.control.setValue(5001);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.inputRef.input.nativeElement.focus();
      this.inputRef.input.nativeElement.blur();
    });`

Comment: This should also work `ngOnInit() {  setTimeout(() => {
      this.control.setValue(+this.inputRef.validateValue(5001))  });  }` We need `setTimeout` because `min` and `max` are not assigned yet during change detection cycle

Comment: @yurzui I think the problem is with how the validators are defined!, could you check my answer if its ok?

Comment: thank you for your explanitation. That helped me a lot to understand the issue. But for some reason calling ````updateValueAndValidity()```` does nothing for me.

Comment: @2803 if you can replicate the issue in the stackblitz, I will check it!

Comment: @NarenMurali calling ```setTimeout``` as @yurzui wrote before helped fixing my issue. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @yurzui You were right :) my bad! good catch!

Answer (score 1):

Validation makes your control valid or invalid. But it doesn't prevent you from changing the value itself using JavaScript. What you can do is read `max`. The simplest solution I came up with:

```
this.control.setValue(value);
if (this.control.errors?.['max']) {
  this.control.setValue(this.control.errors?.['max'].max);
}
```

You may want to use additional setValue options in this case if you need to prevent double event firing.